# Getting the Key value for a complex nested dictionary/ array combination in Swift

Tags: ios, swift

I am trying to access the keys for the following Dictionary:

```
let dictionaryToUSe = ["Starter":["mealName":"hamburger","price":"20.00"],"MainCourse":["mealName":"hotdog","price":"30.00"] ]
let keysToUse = dictionaryToUSe.keys  
print(keysToUse) // returns "LazyMapCollection<Dictionary<String, Dictionary<String, String>>, String>(_base: ["Starter": ["price": "20.00", "mealName": "hamburger"]], _transform: (Function))\n"
```

How do I access the "starter" string? 
and how do I generate a list of the keys for the "dictionaryToUSe" Dictionary?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To get the list of the dictionary keys, generate an array from the LazyMapCollection:

```
let keysToUse = Array(dictionaryToUSe.keys)
```

Result:

> ["Starter", "MainCourse"]

But to access the values from the dictionary, use classic subscripting:

```
if let starter = dictionaryToUSe["Starter"] {
    print(starter)  // ["price": "20.00", "mealName": "hamburger"]
    if let price = starter["price"] {
        print(price) // "20.00"
    }
    // etc
}
```